# SQLite performance tuning for paginated fetches

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I am trying to optimize the query I use for fetching paginated data from database with large data sets.

My schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    custom_fields TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE events (
    event_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    organizer_id TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    type TEXT NOT NULL,
    start_time INTEGER,
    duration INTEGER
    -- more columns here, omitted for the sake of simplicity
);

CREATE INDEX events_organizer_id_start_time_idx ON events(organizer_id, start_time);
CREATE INDEX events_organizer_id_type_idx ON events(organizer_id, type);
CREATE INDEX events_organizer_id_type_start_time_idx ON events(organizer_id, type, start_time);
CREATE INDEX events_type_start_time_idx ON events(type, start_time);
CREATE INDEX events_start_time_desc_idx ON events(start_time DESC);
CREATE INDEX events_start_time_asc_idx ON events(IFNULL(start_time, 253402300800) ASC);

CREATE TABLE event_participants (
    participant_id TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    event_id TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES events(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    role INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    UNIQUE (participant_id, event_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);

CREATE INDEX event_participants_participant_id_event_id_idx ON event_participants(participant_id, event_id);
CREATE INDEX event_participants_event_id_idx ON event_participants(event_id);

CREATE TABLE event_tag_maps (
    event_id TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES events(event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    tag_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, tag_id) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);

CREATE INDEX event_tag_maps_event_id_tag_id_idx ON event_tag_maps(event_id, tag_id);
```

Where in **events** table I have around **1,500,000** entries, and around **2,000,000** in **event_participants**.

Now, a typical query would look something like:

```
SELECT
    EVTS.event_id,
    EVTS.type,
    EVTS.name,
    EVTS.time,
    EVTS.duration
 FROM events AS EVTS
 WHERE
 EVTS.organizer_id IN(
     'f39c3bb1-3ee3-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '4555e70f-3f1d-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '6e7e33ae-3f1c-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '4850a6a0-3ee4-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     'e06f784c-3eea-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     'bc6a0f73-3f1d-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '68959fb5-3ef3-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     'c4c96cf2-3f1a-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '727e49d1-3f1b-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008',
     '930bcfb6-3f09-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008')

    AND EVTS.type IN('Meeting', 'Conversation')
    AND(
      EXISTS (
          SELECT  1 FROM event_tag_maps AS ETM WHERE ETM.event_id = EVTS.event_id AND
             ETM.tag_id IN ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '6ae6870f-1aac-11e6-aeb9-005056c00008', '6ae6870c-1aac-11e6-aeb9-005056c00008', '1f6d3ccb-eaed-4068-a46b-ec2547fec1ff'))
      OR NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT  1 FROM event_tag_maps AS ETM WHERE ETM.event_id = EVTS.event_id)
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM event_participants AS EPRTS
            WHERE
                EVTS.event_id = EPRTS.event_id
                AND participant_id NOT IN('79869516-3ef2-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008', '79869515-3ef2-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008', '79869516-4e18-11e6-a0dc-005056c00008')
    )
 ORDER BY IFNULL(EVTS.start_time, 253402300800) ASC
 LIMIT 100 OFFSET @Offset;
```

Also, for fetching the overall count of the query-matching items, I would use the above query with count(1) instead of the columns and without the *ORDER BY* and *LIMIT/OFFSET* clauses.

I experience two main problems here:

1) The performance drastically decreases as I increase the *@Offset* value. The difference is very significant - from being almost immediate to a number of seconds.

2) The count query takes a long time (number of seconds) and produces the following execution plan:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE events AS EVTS
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event_tag_maps AS ETM USING COVERING INDEX event_tag_maps_event_id_tag_id_idx (event_id=? AND tag_id=?)
1|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 2
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event_tag_maps AS ETM USING COVERING INDEX event_tag_maps_event_id_tag_id_idx (event_id=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE event_participants AS EPRTS USING INDEX event_participants_event_id_idx (event_id=?)
```

Here I don't understand why the full scan is performed instead of an index scan.

**Additional info and SQLite settings used:**

- I use *System.Data.SQLite* provider (have to, because of custom functions support)
- Page size = cluster size (4096 in my case)
- Cache size = 100000
- Journal mode = WAL
- Temp store = 2 (memory)
- No transaction is open for the query

Is there anything I could do to change the query/schema or settings in order to get as much performance improvement as possible?

Comment: Does `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(1)` help?

Comment: [Don't use OFFSET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13018014/11654).

Comment: @CL. a) count(*) has the same performance; b) I'll look into omitting OFFSET

Comment: @CL. can't omit OFFSET, I have an unordered stream of queries, i.e., each next query not necessary requests the page immediately after the previous one.